# Создание одно- и двухпанельных макетов приложений Андроид. Проблемы и ошибки

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я пишу приложение, где должно быть реализовано два режима разметки: однопанельный для телефонов (Frag1) и двухпанельный для планшетов (Frag1+Frag2). Следую руководству Android. Ссылка на руководство: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

**Что происходит:**

**1)** смена ориентации с ландшафтного на портретный: создается фрагмент Frag1 (однопанельный режим)

**2)** смена ориентации с портретного на ландшафтный: создается 3 фрагмента (Frag1 однопанельный режим, Frag1 двухпанельный режим, Frag2 двухпанельный режим). Не должно так быть.

**3)** если мы сначала запустим приложение в ландшафтном режиме, а затем повернем в портретный режим: фрагмент Frag1 (однопанельный режим) будет пуст, т.е. не создается вообще

**Вопрос:** почему фрагмент Frag1 в однопанельном режиме (который я создаю программно, но использую FrameLayout, определенный в макете как контейнер) инициализируется дважды? Как решить эту проблему?

**Код из руководства на GitHub:** https://github.com/FaytMaruf/fragmenttutorial/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/maruf/fragmenttutorial

(Похоже, руководства Google Android содержат ошибки в коде)

Comment: Приведите код и разметку в вопросе текстом, просто ссылки мало

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то в `Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс - Программирование под Android` очень подробно расписано решение данной задачи.

Comment: @post_zeew, спасибо за наводку, уже изучаю. Книга аж на 600 страниц, 14-й год. Боюсь, чтобы не использовать устаревшие техники.

Comment: @Trancer, Есть издание 2016-го года.